# Batch .txt to .csv conversion

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file

I need to convert txt file which content looks like:

```
IP Address= 10.191.128.236 
 
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1 = PX44025A
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1 = 10.191.128.236
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1 = TRP-80G1000MB-1A
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1 = BB CKT          
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1 = NWA-078320-003  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1 = EXBB            
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1 = NWA-078332-001  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1 = 3.51
.............................................
 
IP Address= 10.191.160.169 
 
Request timed out.
.............................................
 
IP Address= 10.191.128.242 
 
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1 = PX44025D
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1 = 10.191.128.242
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1 = TRP-80G1000MB-1A
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1 = BB CKT          
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1 = NWA-078320-003  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1 = EXBB            
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1 = NWA-078332-001  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1 = 3.51
.............................................
```

You can get sample source files from http://x.x.x.x/Convert/ if you want to test your script.
Header should be prepared base on items before "=" then informations after "=" and between "..........." should be placed in a rows (separate row for each IP address), as in below example:

```
IP Address,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1, 1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1, 1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1

10.191.128.236,PX44025A,10.191.128.236,TRP-80G1000MB-1A,BB CKT,NWA-078320-003,3.10.09,3.10.09,EXBB,NWA-078332-001,3.51
10.191.160.169,Request timed out.
10.191.128.242,PX44025D,10.191.128.242,TRP-80G1000MB-1A,BB CKT,NWA-078320-003,3.10.09,3.10.09,EXBB,NWA-078332-001,3.51
```

Of course file can contain more data, above is just an example.
I tried to create my own batch using for /f, tokens, delims, etc. but finaly gave up...
Can anyone help me to prepare it?

The output will be used to import to Excel (which will allow filter file contents).

Below see my "hard work":

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo IP Address,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1, 1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1, 1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1,1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1 >out.csv 
for %%i in (Input.txt) do (
  set "x="
  for /f "tokens=2,3,4,5 delims=:=" %%a in (Input.txt) do set x=!x!%%a %%b %%c %%d,
  set x=!x:  =!
  set x=!x:       =!
  set x=!x:~0,-1!
  echo !x!>>out.csv
)
```

The problem is that I do not know how to move to next line when necessary...
Thanks in advance for your kind support!

Comment: Without making any attempt to look into the content of your file properly, it seems apparent to me that this sort of data transposing is not something that batch files could easily do. I'd expect powershell to better support this kind of work, if that's an option, add the powershell tag to your opening post to attract a more suitable audience.

Comment: Is the order and length of this ?SNMP-database? elements constant?

Comment: Powershell is an option as long as does not require additional software. Unfortunately don't know it at all, so only ready-to-use example can help me. Base on it I can start learning :-) Regarding order and lenght - its an output from snmp4j tool grabbed to txt file.

Comment: The golden question: why are you doing this? Is it to import into a database? You could just import the original file and do the work in the database.

Comment: Need to import it into Excel to let other users to sort data easily. Source file contails data for thousands of IP's.

Comment: Please describe the rules for the conversion! With an example only, users might interpret something wrongly and provide unsatisfactory solutions then...

Comment: Tried to explain rules (just edited) but maybe not clear enough, That's why shared source files (two files with bit different contents) to let everybody test his script. Seems (base on answers received) that it is quite clear what I need to get as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solutions below make no assumptions about the order or number of rows in each section. They work even if the order varies, or if some IPs are missing values. The script also removes leading and trailing spaces from all values.

For performance testing, I replicated the OP's sample data to ~1.6 MB with 3660 IP addresses.

Here is a fast and robust solution that works as long as the header fits within the batch 8kb variable size limit. The 1.6 MB file took 24 seconds to process.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "input=test.txt"
set "output=fast.csv"

:: Clear $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

for /f "delims== " %%N in ('findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*\." "%input%"') do set "$%%N=1"
set "header="
for /f "delims=$=" %%N in ('set $') do set "header=!header!,%%N"

>"%output%" (
  echo IP Address!header!
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims== " %%A in ("%input%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "IP" (
      set "ip=%%~nxB"
      for %%V in (!header!) do set "$%%V="
    ) else if "%%A" equ "Request" (
      echo !ip:* =!,Request timed out.
      set "ip="
    ) else if "%%B" equ "" (
      if "%%A" equ "............................................." if defined ip (
        set "ln=!ip:* =!"
        for %%V in (!header!) do set "ln=!ln!,!$%%V!"
        echo !ln!
        set "ip="
      )
    ) else set "$%%A=%%~nxB"
  )
)
```

And here is a slower solution that should always work, regardless of the header size. This version took 98 seconds to process the 1.6 MB file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "input=test.txt"
set "output=slow.csv"

:: Clear $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

for /f "delims== " %%N in ('findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*\." "%input%"') do set "$%%N=1"

<nul >"%output%" (
  set /p "=IP Address"
  for /f "delims=$=" %%N in ('set $') do set /p "=,%%N"
  echo(
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims== " %%A in ("%input%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "IP" (
      set "ip=%%~nxB"
      for /f "delims=$=" %%N in ('set $') do set "_%%N="
    ) else if "%%A" equ "Request" (
      echo !ip:* =!,Request timed out.
      set "ip="
    ) else if "%%B" equ "" (
      if "%%A" equ "............................................." if defined ip (
        set /p "=!ip:* =!"
        for /f "delims=$=" %%N in ('set $') do set /p "=,!_%%N!"
        echo(
        set "ip="
      )
    ) else set "_%%A=%%~nxB"
  )
)
```

---

**EDIT** Here is the fast code with extensive comments

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "input=%~1"
set "output=fast.csv"

:: Clear $ variables
for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

:: Scan entire file for a list of unique header entries
:: only look at lines that begin number followed by a dot.
:: For each found value, define a variable named ${address}, with a value of 1
for /f "delims== " %%N in ('findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*\." "%input%"') do set "$%%N=1"

:: Build a comma delimited list of addresses for the header
:: by scanning all the $ variables
set "header="
for /f "delims=$=" %%N in ('set $') do set "header=!header!,%%N"

:: Enclose remaining code in parens and redirect once for better speed.
>"%output%" (

  %= Print out the header line =%
  echo IP Address!header!

  %= Parse all lines of file into two tokens, delimited by = and/or space =%
  %= 1* means the 2nd token can include delimiters                        =%
  for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims== " %%A in ("%input%") do (

    if "%%A" equ "IP" (
      %= IP Address line =%
      set "ip=%%~nxB"                         %= Save the IP Address   =%
      for %%V in (!header!) do set "$%%V="    %= Clear all $ variables =%

    ) else if "%%A" equ "Request" (
      %= Request timed out. line =%
      (echo !ip:* =!,Request timed out.) %= Write out the "timed out" line =%
      set "ip="                          %= Clear ip so no other output for this section =%

    ) else if "%%B" equ "" (  %= Only one token =%
      if "%%A" equ "............................................." if defined ip (
        %= Only process if end of IP Address and ip is still defined =%

        set "ln=!ip:* =!"  %= Initialize line as IP Address =%
                           %= Remove all leading text up through the first space =%

        %= Append the value of each $variable to line, with leading comma =%
        %= Order of values is guaranteed to match header =%
        for %%V in (!header!) do set "ln=!ln!,!$%%V!"

        (echo !ln!)      %= Write the data line =%
        set "ip="        %= Clear ip so no more output until next IP Address =%
      )

    ) else set "$%%A=%%~nxB"   %= Main data line - Save value in $ variable         =%
                               %= ~nx treats the value as a file name and extension =%
                               %= so trailing space(s) are removed                  =%
  )
)
```

---

**Very fast JREPL.BAT solution**

Just for fun, I decided to implement a solution using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - a regular expression command line text processor written as hybrid batch/JScript. Unlike my pure batch solutions, this JREPL solution assumes that all IP Addresses have the same number of lines of data, with the same addresses. This is not as robust, but it is what most other people assumed in their answers.

Using JREPL.BAT, I cut the processing time of input1.txt from 4.5 seconds down to 0.8 seconds. But most of that time is spend initializing JScript. The performance of JREPL really begins to shine as the size of the input file increases. For example, the 1.6 MB test file took 24 seconds with my "fast" pure batch solution, and my JREPL solution takes only 2 seconds!

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "input=test.txt"
set "output=jrepl.csv"

:: Compute and write header
call jrepl "^\d[\d.]+"^
           "head+=','+$0;$txt=false"^
           /inc "/^\d+\.//:/^\.+/"^
           /jbeg "var head='IP Address'"^
           /jend "output.WriteLine(head)"^
           /jmatchq /f "%input%" /o "%output%"

:: Compute and append data
call jrepl "^IP Address\s*=\s*([\d.]+)@^Request timed out\.@^[\d.]+\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$@^[.]+"^
           "x=$2;$txt=false;@x+=','+$0;$txt=false;@x+=','+$5;$txt=false;@$txt=x"^
           /t @ /jmatchq /jbeg "var x" /f "%input%" >>"%output%"
```

Comment: Something is wrong with both scripts. Header is created fine but body has only first item  and then comma's. You can test your batch on source files pointed at question (just addes link to sample files) if you have some time and good will to help :-)

Comment: @MrM - I don't know what you did wrong. But I copied the first solution from this answer into a new batch script, ran it against your input1.txt sample, and it worked flawlessly (4.6 seconds). Despite the multiple edits to my answer, I haven't made any changes to the code, only the accompanying text. Copy my code again and try again.

Comment: @MrM - I don't think my code has any Windows version dependency, but what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. I think the issue is that sample text/code given in question has different structure than source file I'm using for testing. Can you please test it on sample files from http://89.171.106.83/Convert/ ?

Comment: @MrM - That is exactly what I did. I tested both input1.txt and input2.txt, with my code, and they worked perfectly. I never get any output with a bunch of commas as you describe. Windows 7 should absolutely work fine with my code.

Comment: Just tested in on three different PC's (Win98, Win7, Win2008 R2) and all of them gives the same result - header is OK but the body looks like: 10.192.14.154,,,,,,,,,,
10.192.14.155,,,,,,,,,,
10.192.129.148,,,,,,,,,,
10.192.129.147,,,,,,,,,,
10.192.129.145,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @MrM - OK, I think I know what the problem is. I believe your input files have tabs in them that I am receiving as spaces. In my input1.txt, the line following each IP Address consists of a single space. If I change that space into a tab, then my original code reproduces your results. I modified my code (edited my answer) to include a tab in the "delims" specification, and then I get the correct result again. However, if any of your data lines have trailing tabs, then I think those unwanted tabs will be included in the output. I believe my code only accounts for trailing spaces.

Comment: That is bit strange as I shared exactly same files I'm using on my PC. Now I have only header in the output file.

Comment: @MrM - It is not uncommon for tabs to be transformed into something else when posted into forums or web pages (It may be browser dependent). I don't see how you get only the header, but the fact that the modification had an impact in the result indicates I am on to something regarding tabs. If you were to post a dropbox (or other) link to the binary image of your input file, then I could probably figure this out. But I'm not sure I want to spend much more time on this question.

Comment: I've added zipped files on http://89.171.106.83/Convert/ You can download is as a zip and then open - should be OK with tabs. Of course if you have some time to have a look. Anyway - thank you very much for your kind support!

Comment: @MrM - It wasn't tabs - it was character 0xA0 on lines before and after each IP Address line. I now can reproduce the problem. When I viewed the text in my browser, 0xA0 showed up as a space, which is why I wasn't getting the problem before. I removed the tabs from my code, and made a change to explicitly look for the string of dots signalling end of an IP Address section. I now get the correct results. Give my modified code a try.

Comment: Working perfectly now :-) Thank you very much again! Now I need to stoudy your code to understand how it works :-)

Comment: @mrm - Extensive comments added to fast code. You might consider accepting an answer :-)

Comment: I'm glad to receive such extensive support. Of course answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41893731.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: Part one - accumulate unique column1 entries from entire file
SET "colones="
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO IF "%%b" neq "" (
 ECHO "!colones!"|FIND "%%a," >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "colones=!colones!,%%a"
)
SET "colones=%colones:~1,-1%"
SET "colones=%colones: ,=,%"
>"%outfile%" ECHO(%colones%
:: Part two - accumulate column2 entries from sections
(
SET "coltwos="
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=*" %%z IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("%%z") DO (
  REM Is this an "IP Address" line?
  IF "%%a"=="IP Address" (
   CALL :report
   SET "coltwos=%%b"
   SET "nextline="
   SET "nodata=Y"
  ) ELSE (
   REM save line following "IP Address" line
   IF NOT DEFINED nextline SET "nextline=%%z"
   IF "%%b" neq "" SET "nodata="&SET "coltwos=!coltwos!,%%b"
  )
 )
)
CALL :report
)>>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:report
IF NOT DEFINED coltwos GOTO :EOF 
SET "coltwos=%coltwos: =%"
IF DEFINED nodata (
 ECHO(%coltwos%,%nextline%
) ELSE (
 ECHO(%coltwos%
)
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q41893731.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Pass1 reads each column 1 entry for all lines containing `=` and accumulates, ignoring duplicates. Then remove the stray leading and trailing characters and replace all `,` with `,`

This is making assumptions since the output requirement isn't clear. the `501.7.2.1.4.1` entry appears to be duplicated and there's a stray space included.

The second pass uses a similar technique to accumulate the contents of the second column, using the appearance of the `IP Address` line to signal that a section is complete and hence can be reported.

The line directly following the `IP Address` line is saved since its contents is simply reproduced if there are no entries in the list.

If an entry is located, `nodata` is cleared signalling that `coltwos` has the accumulated report. If no data was located, `coltwos`+`nextline` contains the required report data.

Note that the first pass *creates* the output file (hence `>`) and the second pass *appends* to that file (hence `>>`)

---

Revision

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41893731.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: Part one - accumulate unique column1 entries from entire file
SET "colones="
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO IF "%%b" neq "" (
 ECHO "!colones!,"|FIND "%%a," >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "colones=!colones!,%%a"
)
SET "colones=%colones:~1,-1%"
SET "colones=%colones: ,=,%"
>"%outfile%" ECHO(%colones%
:: Part two - accumulate column2 entries from sections
(
SET "coltwos="
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=*" %%z IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("%%z") DO (
  REM Is this an "IP Address" line?
  IF "%%a"=="IP Address" (
   CALL :report
   SET "coltwos=%%b"
   SET "nextline="
   SET "nodata=Y"
  ) ELSE (
   REM save line following "IP Address" line
   IF NOT DEFINED nextline SET "nextline=%%z"
   IF "%%b" neq "" SET "nodata="&SET "coltwos=!coltwos!,%%b"
  )
 )
)
CALL :report
)>>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:report
IF NOT DEFINED coltwos GOTO :EOF 
SET "coltwos=%coltwos: ,=,%"
if "%coltwos%" neq "%coltwos: ,=%" GOTO report
SET "coltwos=%coltwos:, =,%"
if "%coltwos%" neq "%coltwos:, =%" GOTO report
IF DEFINED nodata (
 ECHO(%coltwos:~1%,%nextline%
) ELSE (
 ECHO(%coltwos:~1%
)
GOTO :eof
```

Given dbenham's critique,the duplication of the header data is cured by appending `,` to the value of `colones` for the `find` so that `colones` appears to have that comma included.

The missing-space problem can be cured by adjusting the way in which spaces are deleted in the `:report` routine, by changing each <kbd>Space</kbd>-<kbd>Comma</kbd> pair with a single comma until no more exist, and then removing the leading space by substringing in the `echo`

Comment: Warning, having read comments - batch line length is limited to about 8K

Comment: Magoo, just tested it and look it works fine. Will analyze results and let you know if somethomh is wrong.

Comment: @MrM - I see two bugs when I run this code - the last value in the header is duplicated at the end (one extra value). And spaces are stripped from values in the body - `BB CKT` becomes `BBCKT`

Comment: @dbenham : Well observed and easy-fixed.

Comment: Magoo, thank you very much - your revised script works perfectly fine. The only issue is it is very slow,. I've tested header and body creation parts separately and header praparation (Part 1)thakes most of the time the script is working. Part 2 is very fast. Anyway batch is working perfecty as expected.

Comment: Yes, your header computation is exceedingly inefficient. Your script takes 2.5 minutes to run, as opposed to 4 sec for my script. I also think I see a flaw in your design. Your header computation allows for varying column1 entries for each IP Address. But your main body section assumes all IP Addresses have the same column1 entries (and in the same order). It works fine with the test data, but if the IP Addresses ever do vary in column1 content, then the output will be corrupted. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41912581/1012053) for a fast solution that allows for varying content,

Answer (score 0):

You should always *describe the specifications* of the problem and not just show an example. The Batch file solution below create the same output you requested, but if the real data have a different format than the example data, this program will fail...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "delim=............................................."
call :procFile > out.csv
goto :EOF


:procFile

rem Create the header
< NUL (
set /P "=IP Address"
for /F "skip=1" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%a" equ "%delim%" goto endHeader
   set /P "=,%%a"
))
:endHeader
echo/

rem Create the rest of data
set "data="
< NUL (
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%a" equ "%delim%" (
      echo !data:~1!
      set "data="
   ) else (
      if defined data set /P "=!data:~1!," & set "data="
      if "%%b" neq "" (
         set "data=%%b"
      ) else (
         if "%%a" neq " " set "data= %%a"
      )
   )
))
exit /B
```

Comment: Aacini - you are right, sometimes format can be bit different. Just tested your script and it is very fast but there are some problems. Is there any chance to send you source file to have a look?

Comment: As I said before, you should _describe the specifications_! Use plain English to explain the points where the real data differ from the example and the required output in such cases; then, post just a couple examples of these cases. Edit the question to add these _new_ requirements and post a comment here as an advice that you completed these steps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution that does not rely on any certain texts in the file, it recognises the separator lines consisting of periods `.`, and the equal-to sign `=`, that separates header from data per each line; if no `=` is found, the line is either empty (or contains <kbd>SPACE</kbd> only), a said separator line (`.`), or an error message (like `Request timed out.` in your sample data).

The file is read once by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), the header is build during reading the first block and is not rebuilt again and again when it has already been done. In case the first block is invalid or incomplete, so no header data can be collected, it is done later, and the header is then written into a temporary file, because there are already data written to the output file; the header is then combined with the data later.

Your sample data contains many trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, so the script can remove up to 15 of them.

Here is the code (see also the numerous explanatory `rem` comments):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILEI=%~1" & rem // (specify input  file by first  command line argument)
set "_FILEO=%~2" & rem // (specify output file by second command line argument)
set "_SEPAR=,"   & rem // (character to use as separator)

rem // Get character with code `0xA0`:
for /F %%N in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo 0xA0"') do (
    set "$A0=%%N"
)

rem // Process input file in sub-routine, write output file:
> "%_FILEO%" call :PROCESS "%_FILEI%" TEMPF
rem /* Variable `TEMPF` is usually empty, so the following code does not run;
rem    however, if the first block in the input file is invalid/incomplete,
rem    the output header is assembled belatedly, so it is stored in a temporary
rem    file and put together with the collected data at the end: */
if defined TEMPF (
    if exist "%TEMPF%" (
        > nul (
            copy /Y /B "%TEMPF%"+"%_FILEO%" "%TEMPF%"
            move /Y "%TEMPF%" "%_FILEO%"
        )
    ) else (
        >&2 echo ERROR: no valid data block encountered, could not built header!
        exit /B 1
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  val_file  rtn_temp_file
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Initialise variables (flags and buffers):
    set "DONE=" & set "NEXT=" & set "TMPF="
    set "HEAD=%_SEPAR%" & set "COLL=%_SEPAR%"
    rem /* Read input file line by line, split at first `=` sign;
    rem    let us call the left part key and the right one value: */
    for /F "usebackq eol== tokens=1,* delims==" %%K in ("%~1") do (
        set "KEY=%%K"
        set "VALUE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Remove potential trailing space from key:
        if "!KEY:~-1!"==" " set "KEY=!KEY:~,-1!"
        rem // Remove potential trailing character with code `0xA0` from key:
        if "!KEY:~-1!"=="!$A0!" set "KEY=!KEY:~,-1!"
        if defined VALUE (
            rem // Remove potential trailing spaces from value:
            for %%N in ("        " "    " "  ") do (
                set "VALUE=!VALUE:%%~N=!"
            )
            if "!VALUE:~-1!"==" " set "VALUE=!VALUE:~,-1!"
            rem // Remove potential leading space from value:
            if "!VALUE:~,1!"==" " set "VALUE=!VALUE:~1!"
            rem /* Build output lines by concatenating values and also
            rem    header lines out of keys; toggle delayed expansion
            rem    in order to not lose exclamation marks; use `for /F`
            rem    loop to transport values over `endlocal` barrier: */
            for /F "delims=" %%M in ("!COLL!!VALUE!!_SEPAR!") do (
                if defined DONE (
                    rem // Header has alread y been built:
                    endlocal
                    set "COLL=%%M"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                ) else (
                    rem // Header has not yet been built, so do it:
                    for /F "delims=" %%N in ("!HEAD!!KEY!!_SEPAR!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "HEAD=%%N" & set "COLL=%%M"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
            )
        ) else (
            rem /* The value is empty, so there are two possibilities:
            rem    either the `.` separator line, or an error message: */
            if "!KEY:.=!"=="" (
                rem // Line consists of `.` only (separator line):
                if not defined DONE (
                    rem // Header has not yet been written:
                    if not defined NEXT (
                        rem // Header is not postponed:
                        if defined TMPF (
                            rem // Write belated header to temporary file:
                            > "!TMPF!" ((echo(!HEAD:~1,-1!) & echo/ )
                        ) else (
                            rem // Normally, return header immediately:
                            ((echo(!HEAD:~1,-1!) & echo/ )
                        )
                    )
                )
                rem // Write collected output data line:
                echo(!COLL:~1,-1!
                endlocal
                rem // Indicate by a flag that header has been completed:
                if not defined NEXT set "DONE=#"
                rem // Reset variables (flags and buffers):
                set "NEXT=" & set "HEAD=%_SEPAR%" & set "COLL=%_SEPAR%"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            ) else if defined KEY (
                rem // Line contains error message (no `=` sign found):
                for /F "delims=" %%M in ("!COLL!!KEY!!_SEPAR!") do (
                    for /F "delims=" %%N in ("!HEAD!!KEY!!_SEPAR!") do (
                        endlocal
                        rem /* Header cannot be written immediately, so create
                        rem    path to temporary file to receive the header: */
                        if not defined DONE set "TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%-1.tmp"
                        set "NEXT=#" & set "HEAD=%%N" & set "COLL=%%M"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
    rem // If applicable, transport temporary file path over `endlocal` barrier:
    (
        endlocal
        set "%~2=%TMPF%"
    )
    exit /B
```

Comment: I've problem to run your script (it cannot find temp file when started). It creates output but without header. Also some empty spaces are added (maybe because it cannot get something from temp file).Please test your script using source file I've shared at question (just edited) if you wish.

Comment: The problem is that your input files contain characters with code `0xA0`, which I assumed to be "normal" spaces; I fixed the script now... Note that it does not use temporary files, except in the (rare) case when the very first block of the input file contains `Request timed out.` rather than normal valid data...

Comment: I didn't even know that 0xA0 is there:-) Your script is working now fine. Thank you very much for your support! Thanks for very useful comments in the code - it allows to understand the code better (especially for newbie like me...).

Answer (score 0):

The **purpose of this answer** is twofold:

- To **demonstrate the power and flexibility of PowerShell**, which allows for a robust, reasonably concise and readable solution that performs reasonably well.
- To show **how to invoke PowerShell-script-based solutions from `cmd.exe`** (a regular Command Prompt) and how to make this process easier with the help of a wrapper batch file.

---

If you create file `Transform.ps1` with the **PowerShell code** posted at the bottom, you can invoke it as follows from `cmd.exe` (a regular Command Prompt) to get the desired output:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -File .\Transform.ps1 input.txt out.csv
```

<sup>* **Use `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestriced` with caution**: only use it with scripts that you trust - see [`Get-Help about_Execution_Policies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Execution_Policies).

* To work with character encodings other than the default one, you can use the `-Encoding` parameter - see below.

* `-NoProfile` skips loading of the PowerShell profile (initialization commands for interactive use).</sup>

If you create **wrapper batch script** `Transform.cmd` with the content posted below and place it in the same directory as the PowerShell script, you can simplify invocation to:

```
Transform input.txt out.csv
```

---

**Contents of wrapper batch file `Transform.cmd`:**

```
@powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*
```

<sup>This wrapper works generically, as long as the filename root of the batch file and the PowerShell script are the same, as in `Transform.cmd` and `Transform.ps1`</sup>

---

**Contents of PowerShell script `Transform.ps1`:**

- **Compatibility**: The code uses PowerShell v3+ features, but it could be made to work with PSv2 too.
- **Character Encoding**: By default, PowerShell's `Default` encoding is used, which is the single-byte, extended-ASCII encoding implied by your system's legacy Windows code-page setting.

  - You can change the encoding to match your input file's by passing `-Encoding <encoding>`, but note that the output file will invariably use the same encoding (although that would be easy to change).
  - The accepted encoding names are `Unicode, BigEndianUnicode, UTF8, UTF7, UTF32, Ascii, Default, Oem, BigEndianUTF32` (see the `-Encoding` parameter description [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/get-content-for-filesystem)), but note that Excel does not recognize CSV files as such with some of them, notably not `Unicode` (UTF-16LE)
- **Performance**: Processing each sample file linked in the question takes less than 2 seconds on my venerable late-2011 MacBook Air, so, unless the files are much larger, performance is presumably acceptable.
- **Comments**: The code is commented at a high level, which is hopefully enough as a starting point for further exploration.

```
# Declare the script's parameters.
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)] [string] $InPath,
  [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2)] [string] $OutPath,
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding] $Encoding = 'Default'
)

# We anticipate no errors, so let's treat even non-terminating ones as 
# terminating.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# The line that separates records.
$recSeparator = '.............................................'

# Get the first record as a single string, so we can later extract the
# CSV column headers from it.
Write-Verbose "Parsing first record to determine header names..."
$firstRec = Get-Content $InPath -Delimiter $recSeparator -Encoding $Encoding |  
  Select-Object -First 1

# Split the first record into an array of lines that contain "="
$firstRecLines = ($firstRec -split '\r?\n') -match '='

# Synthesize the CSV header line from the array of header names obtained from
# the LHS of the "=" on each line.
$colHeaderList = ($firstRecLines -replace '^([^=]+).*', '$1').Trim() -join ','

# Write the header line plus a blank line to the output file.
# The output encoding.
Write-Verbose "Writing header names to '${OutPath}' using encoding '${Encoding}'.."
$colHeaderList + [Environment]::NewLine | Set-Content $OutPath -Encoding $Encoding

# Now process all records and add a line of data fields (only) for each.
Write-Verbose "Processing all records and appending data rows..."
Get-Content $InPath -Delimiter $recSeparator -Encoding $Encoding | ForEach-Object {
  # Split the record at hand into an array of lines...
  $lines = $_ -split '\r?\n'
  # ... and extract the values (the RHS of "=") as an array.
  $values = $lines -match '=' -replace '^.*= (.*)', '$1'
  # Process the values based on how many were found in the record.
  switch ($values.count) {
    0 { return } # Assumed to be the empty record at the end -> ignore
    1 { # Only 1 value? -> must be a "request timed out" record.
      $valuesList = $values[0].Trim() + ',' + $lines[-2]
      break
    } 
    default { # regular data record
      # Join the trimmed values with ',' to form a CSV data line.
      $valuesList = ($values).Trim() -join ','
    }
  }
  # Append the data line to the output file.
  # The output encoding.
  Add-Content -Value $valuesList $OutPath -Encoding $Encoding
}

Write-Verbose "Processing to output file '${OutPath}' completed successfully"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read file and do some blank line / specific newline removal.
2. Strip out the "Request timed out" lines for later, because they break the block pattern.
3. Regex massage the blocks into PowerShell hashtable/object shape.
4. `eval` them into live objects, then convert those to CSV.
5. Add the "Request timed out" lines to the end of the CSV.
6. It's already regex heavy and unreadable, and the question is answered and accepted, so why not codegolf it a bit too.

~339 characters:

```
$T,$B=(((gc -raw Input2.txt)-replace"(?m)^\s*`r`n"-replace
"(?i)\s*`r`n(?=R)",", ")-split"`r`n").where({$_-match'timed out'},'split')
((($B-join"`r`n")-replace"(?m)^(.+?)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s+$","'`$1'='`$2';"-replace
"(?m)^\.[.`r`n]+","},"-replace"'IP","[PSCustomObject]@{'IP").TrimEnd(",")|
iex|ConvertTo-Csv -N)+@($T-replace'^.*= ')|sc out.csv
```

Sample output:

```
"IP Address","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1"
"10.192.6.199","PI13217A","10.192.6.199","MDP-400MB-1AA","MC-A4","NWA-055298-101","3.00.37","3.00.37"
"10.192.28.73","PI11747A","10.192.28.73","MDP-400MB-1AA","MC-A4","NWA-055298-101","3.00.37","3.00.37"
"10.192.28.74","PI12844A","10.192.28.74","MDP-400MB-1AA","MC-A4","NWA-055298-101","3.00.37","3.00.37"
"10.192.28.75","PI12604A","10.192.28.75","MDP-400MB-1AA","MC-A4","NWA-055298-101","3.02.20","3.02.20"
"10.192.28.78","PI14189A","10.192.28.78","MDP-400MB-1AA","MC-A4","NWA-055298-101","3.00.37","3.00.37"
10.192.15.137, Request timed out.
10.192.16.144, Request timed out.
10.192.136.201, Request timed out.
10.192.1.199, Request timed out.
10.192.153.132, Request timed out.
```

(Yes the last lines aren't quoted the same way, but Excel 2013 handles it)

Answer (score -1):

Your requested output is not valid CSV. All rows need to have the same amount of columns. The row with the error doesn't have that and putting the error in a random property is not a good solution. I suggest adding a `status` column to address this issue. I'm not that familiar with advanced batch-scripting, so here's an example using PowerShell:

```
#Sample data
$str = @"
IP Address= 10.191.160.169 
 
Request timed out.
.............................................
 
IP Address= 10.191.128.236 
 
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1 = PX44025A
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1 = 10.191.128.236
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1 = TRP-80G1000MB-1A
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1 = BB CKT          
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1 = NWA-078320-003  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1 = EXBB            
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1 = NWA-078332-001  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1 = 3.51
.............................................
 
IP Address= 10.191.128.242 
 
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1 = PX44025D
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1 = 10.191.128.242
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1 = TRP-80G1000MB-1A
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1 = BB CKT          
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1 = NWA-078320-003  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1 = 3.10.09
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1 = EXBB            
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1 = NWA-078332-001  
1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1 = 3.51
.............................................
"@

#Read from file as single string (uncomment to use)
#$str = Get-Content -Path C:\File.txt -Raw

#Pattern to match every "IP address <everything until> ............" to split the Devices in the input
$pattern = "(?ms)ip address=\s+(.+?)\s+?$.+?\s+(.+?)(?=\.{10,})"

$devices = Select-String -InputObject $str -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | ForEach-Object {
    #Foreach device
    $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "IP" = $_.Groups[1].Value
        "Status" = "OK"
    }

    #Get values
    $valuearray = $_.Groups[2].Value.Split("`r`n",[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    #If more than one line = status ok, convert data
    #If not, skip to else and update status.
    if($valuearray.Count -gt 1) {
        $valuearray| ForEach-Object {
            #Add values
            $name,$val = $_.Trim() -split ' = '
            Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $name -Value $val
        }

    } else {
        $obj.Status = $valuearray[0]
    }

    #Output device
    $obj
}

#Get all unique properties (if first object has only IP and Status, every other would be exported with only those without this fix)
$PropertyList = $devices | ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } } | Select-Object -Unique 

$devices | Select-Object -Property $PropertyList | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Patch "C:\out.csv"
```

Output:

```
"IP","Status","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.5.1.1.1.6.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.10.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.4.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.7.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.1.1.1.8.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.3.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.4.1","1.3.6.1.4.1.119.2.3.69.501.7.2.1.5.1"
"10.191.160.169","Request timed out.",,,,,,,,,,
"10.191.128.236","OK","PX44025A","10.191.128.236","TRP-80G1000MB-1A","BB CKT","NWA-078320-003","3.10.09","3.10.09","EXBB","NWA-078332-001","3.51"
"10.191.128.242","OK","PX44025D","10.191.128.242","TRP-80G1000MB-1A","BB CKT","NWA-078320-003","3.10.09","3.10.09","EXBB","NWA-078332-001","3.51"
```

Comment: Use ".........." as a line separator, put "Request timed out" to second column (first is IP address), rest of colums leave empty for that row, then go to next line/row on ".........." ?

Comment: That would require that you know every property. I would create something dynamic in which case I don't know how many properties there are and what they are called before execution.

Comment: Something not being possible is still an answer... However, I've updated answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: The "I don't know how to solve this with a Batch file" meaning of your answer can barely be a comment, but certainly not an answer. I suppose that in PowerShell would be extremely difficult to show the columns without quotes and without the additional commas in the "Request timed out." line, as requested by the OP...

Comment: What? It's one sentence to show the that answer is not a fixed version of his batch-approach but rather a new solution (which OP accepts). As for the quotes, that's just a preference (unless delimiter is used in the value) and something PowerShell's CSV-cmdlets adds them by defualt unless you want to do manual text-writing and -parsing. OP asked for CSV which uses some rules (same fields on every row) and adding the error to a random column (which you don't know the name of in case the input is changed in the future, ex. querying new type of devices) is bad.

Comment: Remember that this is not a store and answers are supposed to be reusable. I will continue to provide answers which includes recommendations based on my experience and best practices. They may not always fit the OP's description perfectly, but then he's free to go with another solution. Any CSV-capable reader will be able to understand my output, unlike the output he asked for which may fail on some. That's why I recommended the changes

Comment: Thanks for sharing your scrips. It will take some time (for me) to test it as PowerShell is totally new for me and I must read how to use it. Anyway - if you want to test your script by yourself - I've shared link to sample source files in my question.

Comment: Regarding your statement: *"Your requested output is not valid CSV. All rows need to have the same amount of columns."* - There has never been a well defined, universally accepted specification for CSV format. It is very common to accept lines that have fewer values (fewer commas). Missing values at the end of a line are defaulted to empty. That being said, it is a good idea to always have a consistent number of values on each line.